# Testing a model with truncated data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, binomial-distribution, censoring

This is probably a simple question.

I'm studying events which have N outcomes, of which exactly one is correct.  N is very large, more than a billion (and is known).  There are many possible events, some of which are tested multiple times.

I would like to test the following model: a given event is tested correctly with probability 1 - p.  Otherwise, the test result is chosen uniformly at random from the N outcomes (hence, almost certainly incorrect).  I want to (1) see if this model is plausible and (2) if so, find p.  p should be small, just a few percent.

The data I have omits events where two or more tests have the same value.  (Because N is large, if two tests have the same value that is likely to be the correct result.)  So what I have is, for each k, the number of different events which have had k different tests, no two of which match.  Most of the events have had k = 1 tests but some have 2, 3, or even more tests.  In most cases one result is correct and the rest are incorrect; in some cases all are incorrect.

How can I test my hypothesis?

Comment: Do you mean events have $N$ outcomes or $N$ *possible* outcomes?  What do you mean by "testing" an event?  ("Tests" seem to have "values" that might or might not be "correct."  Does this mean a "test" is a measurement of something?)  Who "chooses" a test result for an incorrect test?  How is the correctness of a test determined?  Is it part of the data or just something hypothetical or theoretical?  What is your "hypothesis"?  It seems to refer to a probability, but it does not appear to make any assertions about the probability.  Do you mean you want to *estimate* $p$ and check for model fit?

Comment: @whuber: Each test is a measurement (with N possible outcomes, yes) which may be correct or incorrect.  I can only discover the correctness or incorrectness through the measurements, but it is true that exactly one outcome is correct, never 0 or 2.

Comment: "Who 'chooses' a test result" is a part of what I'm trying to test -- the guess is that all are equally likely if there is a measurement failure.  The hypothesis is that the model itself is a reasonable fit for the data, for any p (which I would then want to estimate); if for k = (1, 2, 3) I had (100, 100, 300) then the model would be a very bad match, regardless of what p value I chose and the number of discarded measurements.